# Theme glitching with newest Version of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I am using the newest (updated) version of IntelliJ IDEA. I am coding in Javascript (React) and i've been using the One Dark theme for ages now.
But since the last update, everything is glitched.

So first problem:
The IDE is now allways starting in the white theme (which is related to the windows theme)
When i try to change the Theme, either nothing happens, or it just doesnt show any Themes, even tho i installed more than 14 (they are disabled tho).

Second problem:
I can not code in Javascript anymore. There is just no collor at all. No marking for functiond etc.

Third problem:
My IDE is crashing almost everytime, I try to open a new, or existing project.

Why is that, has someone simular issues, and what can i do, to prevent having to reinstall my IDE, as i do not want to set my IDE up again.

Thank you in regards

Comment: javascript tag is irrelavant to this question

Comment: @AnujaNimesh yep, got it. thank you

Comment: Check the IDE log (Help | Show Log in Finder), are there any exceptions there?

Comment: Nope... I just cant stop thinking, i kinda destroyed the IDE by ading too many tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to reinstall. But you can save the Config file.
So you can keep all your settings.

Here are the Paths for windows
Windows:

Configuration: %APPDATA%\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3
Plugins: %APPDATA%\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins
System: %LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3
Logs: %LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\log

Hope this helped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).